# how to test the redux update logic in the doc examples

Tags: redux

in this part
https://redux.js.org/basics/store#dispatching-actions

> let's verify our program works! Even without any UI, we can already test the update logic.

is there anyone can tell me how to test the update logic?

node doesn't the import syntax

Answer (score 0):

When they say, "Even without any UI, we can already test the update logic" look at lines 12 and 13 in the code snippet below that:

```
// Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))
```

They are saying that even without any UI changing along with this change of state, you can see the change of state being logged to the console. They then show a screenshot of the [Redux chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) which is another way you can see the redux state changing.

If the import syntax is giving you trouble, try the Es5 CommonJS syntax, something like this:

```
var createStore = require('redux').createStore
```

From the [redux docs](http://var%20createStore%20=%20require('redux').createStore).

Hope this helps.